# How to remove gaps between FRAMEs without hurting HTML validity?

Tags: html, frame

I know frames are bad. However I have to stick with them a little longer. My problem comes from the  non-standard "border" attribute of the "frameset" element:

```
<frameset border="0">
...
</frameset>
```

If I don't use that attribute browsers put a gap between each frame. If I use the attribute, HTML validators throw error about "unsupported attribute".

Now I hear you saying "use it and ignore the validator", that's fine. I think I can live with one validator warning, and browsers seem not too worried about it either :)

My question is mostly about HTML trickery. How can I set border to 0 and yet stay browser compatible? Think of this as an exercise for similar problems in the future. For instance I tried:

```
<frameset onload="this.border='0'">
```

and it didn't work.

I tried using stylesheets in inner frames to set "border:0;margin:0;padding:0", it didn't work either. Gap seems to come from an unknown source.

I thought of writing  in Javascript like:

```
document.write('<frameset border="0">');
```

But I have a hunch that it wouldn't validate anyway.

Can you think of an alternate solution?

---

Other solutions that didn't work:

- @Donut: "frameborder" attribute on either "frame" or "frameset" elements
- @kangax: frameSetObj.setAttribute('border', 0);

Comment: How about `yourFramesetEl.setAttribute('border', 0)` instead of `yourFramesetEl.border = 0`?

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either.

Comment: Need to see actual page to tell what's going on there.

Comment: http://sozluk.sourtimes.org/default.htm

Comment: What browsers do these gaps appear on? I couldn't reproduce (or see) it with FF 3.5.3, IE8, Opera 10 even though I got rid of all the border, frameborder attributes and tested.

Comment: IE8, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10, Chrome 3. Gaps are smaller (2-3 pixels) in Opera and IE, wider (5-6 pixels) in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my tests, these should work :

For Opera (10) :

```
frameSetObj.setAttribute("framespacing", "0");
```

For IE8 :

```
frameSetObj.setAttribute("framespacing", "0");
//set rows and cols attributes again if the frameset already had them.
frameSetObj.setAttribute("rows", rows);
frameSetObj.setAttribute("cols", cols);
```

For FireFox 3.5 and Chrome 3

```
frameSetObj.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
//same idea as IE8
frameSetObj.setAttribute("rows", rows);
frameSetObj.setAttribute("cols", cols);
```

To summarize, this code should work on every browser:

```
frameSetObj.setAttribute("framespacing", "0");
frameSetObj.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
frameSetObj.setAttribute("rows", rows);
frameSetObj.setAttribute("cols", cols);
```

Comment: Yes this works like a charm. Creates a small nudge effect due to latency of onload event though, so I think this trick is far from being usable in real world scenarios. I took the liberty of adding a summary code at the end of your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`frameborder`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#adef-frameborder) attribute on your **`frame`** tags instead of `border` on the `frameset` tag. [According](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.2.1) to the HTML spec, there is no `border` (or `frameborder`) attribute defined for `frameset` tags.
 In fact, all of the the W3C's page on [frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html) is worth checking out. The [example found there](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#h-16.1) might be helpful to take a look at. You'll also want to make sure you're using a correct `DOCTYPE`. 
In the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```